# Windows 10 and Samba - one direction only

Tags: windows, networking, samba

I have desktop and laptop computers, where both have Windows 10 Pro. From laptop to desktop Samba share is working properly, in Total Commander I can see my desktop's C drive. But the other way is not working - the error message is "Access denied" even if I provide proper credentials - tried both by computer name and IP address. I've installed SMB/CIFS and SNMP on both computers, they are in "Private" network, the sharing is enabled. What do I need to do to connect from desktop to laptop?

Comment: Disable the Windows FW on the laptop and then try accessing the remote share on the laptop from the desktop. If it works, then you likely need to open up SMB access and/or TCP port number in the Windows FW on the laptop to be allowed thru from the local subnet.

Comment: Turning off firewall didn't helped, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is present on TP-Link routers TL-WR1043N V5 with 10.0.0.0/8 network and 1.0.3 build 20161118 rel. 64282 (4555) firmware. I had similar problem with Raspberry Pi connected via Ethernet link. TP-Link support said that for this router there will be new firmware which will fix the issue for that network.